# "off from work" vs. "off work"

Tags: meaning

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/day-off)

> day off: a day when you do not work

I understand the meaning of it.  This post is focused on the opposite of it.
Consider the following conversation.

> Anthony: "Where were you last night?  I was trying to drop by you."
>
> Kevin: "I worked late. I didn't **get off work** until midnight."

Even though I didn't find the definition on [the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off%20work) or [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=get+off+work), I’m pretty sure "someone gets off work" means the employee gets the permission to stop working and go home.

The question is whether "off from work" means the same thing.

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off%20work%20until%2Coff%20from%20work%20until&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coff%20work%20until%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coff%20from%20work%20until%3B%2Cc0) shows that both are in use, though the latter seems to have a different meaning.

Do they mean the same thing? If not,  what does "off from work" mean? Does "off from work" go with the meaning at the beginning of the post?

Comment: When talking about leave, _a day off work_ and _a day off from work_ mean the same thing. Kevin is talking about finishing work when he has had to stay past his usual time. I think it would be possible to express that as 'I didn't get off from work until...' If someone did, it would certainly mean the same thing.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. And "get off work" is clearer and more common, right?

Comment: That's what I implied when I said that I _thought_ 'off from work' could be used with the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

An employee has ***a day off from work*** if and only if the employer of the employee grants the employee permission to stay home.

The phrase "**off from work**" can be coupled with a unit of time other than one day.

It is common to say somthing like,

> I get off from work at 5:00pm Mountain Standard Time
>
> my shift ends at 5:00 pm

The employee has permission to stop working and go home.